# What does it mean when there are two 1s with a curve over a note?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, tuplet

I have never seen this kind of symbol before and google has failed me.

This notation occurs in Chopin Nocturne Op. 9, No. 1, measure 2 beats 4–6.

[image: Chopin Nocturne Op. 9, No. 1, measure 2 beats 4–6]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's an 11-tuplet. Like a triplet, but with 11 notes where there would otherwise be 8 (or some other power of 2).

Comment: It's also incorrectly notated: the 11-tuplet sign should be on the beam side

Answer (score 1):

According to Wiktionary, the word to denote this is [undecuplet or hendecuplet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/triplet#See_also), although there are no articles for those words as of 8 June 2021.